# Overlay an included PDF with text

Tags: pdf, pdfpages

I would like to type on to a PDF document using LaTeX. Using the package `pdfpages` I can load the PDF in to a TeX document. Is there a way to also overlay my own text, using LaTeX? (In particular, a professor has generated a notes document and instead of printing and taking notes by hand I would prefer to take them directly on to the PDF, using TeX).

Comment: Welcome! Don't do this. It is only worth doing when worth the pain. For example, to fill in an application form which is supplied only as a PDF and not designed as a fillable form. If you are talking about taking notes in lectures, either print the notes and write or take notes separately from the document provided. There is no fluent way to add notes to the existing PDF. It will merely distract you and you will end up missing 75% of what's said trying to add notes on 5% of what's said. (The other 20% you'll hear but won't manage to get down.) Seriously. If you must annotate, use a viewer.

Comment: Print it out, scribble on it in class, retype at leisure.

Comment: there are readers (adobe for example) that allow adding notes and even scribbling on the document

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2):

You want the `overpic` package: http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/overpic/

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to use overpic with the pdfpages package? I would like to populate the pdf pages in full size and then lay tex over them.

Comment: If you include the pages one at a time, then you can get the control needed to do this sort of thing on a per page basis, but it's probably just as easy to use \includegraphics --- agree w/ cfr that it's probably easier to use a pen tablet system, print the file into a tool such as jarnal and write directly on it.